# How to find files program is using in the AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I am trying to find the file a program is using so I can write a query using its fields. How would I look at the programs files to see what it is using?

I have tried looking for the file using infor XA, I have tried searching though different libraries for the program, and I have tried looking for command to call or display the program's files but cannot find anything. I looking for the process to review the code or files for the program.

Comment: If it's RPG, you need to scan through the source looking for the file name and/or it's logical files and/or it's record format name.  You didn't mention what type of programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Display Program References (DSPPGMREF)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=ssw_ibm_i_73/cl/dsppgmref.html) command will list the objects a program references.

The other option is to "Display open files" with a "Display Job" (DSPJOB) while the program is active.

Comment: DSPPGMREF has several instances where it is not accurate:
UPDPGM will add new files, but not remove files taken out of the program
Also, the file used at runtime depends upon the library list and any OVRDBF commands.

Comment: Here is another issue with DSPPGMREF, though it is more of an issue with linking with modules rather than service programs. If you like with a module containing procedures, all the files in the module appear as used even if the procedures the program calls do not use the file at all. To fix this, you should link with service programs rather than modules.

Comment: hey @BuckCalabro, how would you find a runtime dependency for a program that uses overrides? Is it a possibility? What if the program doesn't know overrides are in effect?

Comment: The usual way to find runtime dependencies is to use a 3rd party cross reference tool (Hawkeye, Arcad, TOTAL/400, etc). A DIY solution is difficult; the vendor tools basically emulate QCMDEXC, and 'apply' OVRxxxF and library list changes. Static analysis like this has gaps where the OVRxxxF commands are built on the fly, for example from a menu system or control table. I think a dynamic system that captures the actual open files at runtime is do-able with the debug APIs as a base.